# <PageTitle> template component/method

Tags: c#, blazor

I have been playing around with Blazor recently and I am wanting to set up a "template" title for my app that I can use on each page and just replace part of, but I am unsure if there is a built in method I can use or if I should just build a component that sits on top of the PageTitle component.

Essentially I would like something along the lines of

```
// mainlayout.razor

<PageTitleTemplate>Welcome to example.com - {template}</PageTitleTemplate>
```

and then on a second page I could do

```
<PageTitle>Home</PageTitle>
```

and when this home page gets rendered the title within the browser tab would look like "Welcome to example.com - Home"

Building a component that kind of does this should be simple enough but it feels like it should be something that already exists and I just don't have the words to describe it when searching for it.

EDIT

It seems like there is no built in method/component to do this so I've mashed together the suggestions from @enet and @MrCakaShaunCurtis to make a component that will pass a template provided in appsettings into a PageTitle component and will replace part of the template with the provided title from each page.

```
// wwwroot/appsettings.json

{
    "PageTitleTemplateOptions": {
        "Template": "Suggest A Dram - {0}"
    }
}
```

```
// PageTitleTemplate.razor

@inject Microsoft.Extensions.Options.IOptions<PageTitleTemplateOptions> MetaOptions

@code
{
    [Parameter]
    public string Title { get; set; } = null!;

    private string GetTitleToDisplay() => MetaOptions.Value.Template.Replace("{0}", Title);
}

<PageTitle>@GetTitleToDisplay()</PageTitle>
```

```
// Program.cs

...builder setup

builder.Services.Configure<PageTitleTemplateOptions>(builder.Configuration.GetSection(nameof(PageTitleTemplateOptions)));

...builder setup and RunAsync()
```

```
// a page in the app

<PageTitleTemplate Title="Home"/>

...page DOM elements
```

Tbh this can definitely be improved but it works for now

Comment: Do you mean [Layouts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/layouts?view=aspnetcore-6.0)?

Comment: @gunr2171 I dont know if a layout would give me that functionality, I'm meaning more like a site wide title that would be displayed in the browser tab, i.e "Stack Overflow - Whe..." and I could switch out some part of the title using the <PageTitle> component. Layouts seem more for site wide DOM elements, but I'll read a bit more into thoes docs just incase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Index.razor

```
@page "/"

@using Microsoft.Extensions.Options

@inject Microsoft.Extensions.Options.IOptions<MetaOptions> metaOptions

<PageTitle>@metaOptions.Value.Title - @metaOptions.Value.SubTitles.Home</PageTitle>

<h1>Hello, world!</h1>

Welcome to your new app.

<SurveyPrompt Title="How is Blazor working for you?" />
```

### Counter.razor

```
@page "/counter"

@using Microsoft.Extensions.Options

@inject Microsoft.Extensions.Options.IOptions<MetaOptions> metaOptions

<PageTitle>@metaOptions.Value.Title - @metaOptions.Value.SubTitles.Counter</PageTitle>
```

### appsettings.json (partial)

```
"Title": "Welcome to example.com",
  "SubTitles": {
    "Home": "Home",
    "Counter": "Counter"
  }


public class Startup
{
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            // ... code removed
            services.Configure<MetaOptions>(Configuration);
           
        }

      // ... code removed

}
```

Note that you can instead of the above create a component that will contain the PageTitle, and instantiate it from each required page. In that case, you'll have to pass a parameter to your component in order to identify the page used. I wouldn't do that as components are expensive and render your app slow.

Note: You add nothing to the MainLayout component...

Comment: I think this is perhaps the best all round solution, combining with @MrCakaShaunCurtis component would achieve as close to what I was thinking as I can get without putting a huge amount of effort in.

Answer (score 3):

What about:

#### MyPageTitle.razor

```
<PageTitle>Welcome to my Site - @this.ChildContent</PageTitle>

@code {
    [Parameter] public RenderFragment? ChildContent { get; set; }
}
```

And index:

```
@page "/"

<MyPageTitle>Hello Blazor</MyPageTitle>

<h1>Hello, world!</h1>

Welcome to your new app.

<SurveyPrompt Title="How is Blazor working for you?" />
```

Comment: You can also combine this with @Enet's `appsettings.json` configuration to make it configurable on a site by site basis.

Comment: This is pretty much what I had planned if there was no build in component or method within Blazor <3 Also agree combining this with @Enet answer would be the best solution